# Show hidden files in SELECT folder only

Tags: terminal, finder, macos

How do I show hidden files in one directory only? I have a development folder that I'd like to see hidden files in, but I don't want to see hidden files anywhere else on my computer.

Here is the code I tried in the terminal to show all hidden files but it's not what I want. Thanks!

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE
killall Finder
```

Comment: If these aren't dotfiles then you can just use `chmod nohidden`. If there's a specific dotfile you want you can make a symlink or alias. But there's no way to do this like you can in Windows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**This isn't possible.** You can either show all hidden files or hide all hidden files. This setting can't be set for individual folders.

<sup>See [this Super User question regarding .htaccess](https://superuser.com/questions/78203/how-to-show-htaccess-files-in-specific-folder-in-the-finder)</sup>